# How to dynamically create rss feed?

Tags: rss

I just created my first rss feed. it worked fine. got it validated. It is basic feed of my recent blog posts. I would like to know if i would dynamically url parameters..

feed would look like this .. http://www.website.com/feed/?category=php.rss...

should show the recent blog posts of category "php". if category changes to "jquery" should show recent posts in "jquery"

How can I build a feed with changing URL parameters or build individual feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

Just get the category name of out of the query string (using whatever standard library you use for that in whatever language you are using), add that as a conditional to whatever method you use to get the data (hopefully some sort of ORM), then drop the results into whatever library you generate the RSS from, just as if it were all the entries.

Comment: +1; 

@Nick To put it simple, just get the category from the URL parameter (in PHP you can accomplish this by using `$categ = $_GET['category']`; `$categ` will be `php.rss` in your case), and than get the data based on this value, i.e. call `GetEntriesByCategory($categ)`. Also, you don't need to put a `.rss` in the category; `http://www.website.com/feed/?category=php` is good enough